# OutofMemory : GC limit exceeded while creating XSSFWorkBook from InputStream

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi, inputstream

I am trying to upload an excel file in a web server and process it in the server. I am using Apache POI library to parse the excel file. The below code I am using -

```
XSSFWorkBook workBook = new XSSFWorkBook(multiPartFile.getInputStream());
```

Server heap size is set to 2gb. If the size of excel file is small (e.g. - 250 Kb) then no problem but for load testing I tried it with a 12 Mb excel file but it failed with OutOfMemory error.

I came to know that creating workbook from InputStream is indeed a memory hungry operation. So Is there any better way to build XSSFWorkBook from InputStream??

Answer (score 2):

The `XSSFWorkbook` can be using up quite some memory "by design" as it provides full random access to all sheets/rows/cells.

There are ways to work with more predictable memory usage, as a consequence they provide less features or require more work on you side.

Take a look at the example [XLSX2CSV](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java) which uses a streaming XLSX parser for reading the information and thus runs with very low memory overhead even for very large documents.

On the side of writing large files, Apache POI provides [SXSSFWorkbook](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf) which allows to write huge spreadsheets without huge memory requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is ok for the OP, but writing the stream to a (temp) file and creating the workbook from that file will be somewhat less memory-hungry.
Quoting from poi 3.9 javadoc, org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(InputStream):

> Open a package. Note - uses quite a bit more memory than open(String), which doesn't need to hold the whole zip file in memory, and can take advantage of native methods

Beware of https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56537 though, if you're going down that road.